# Calculating the surface integral of a vector field over a surface using divergence theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

SO I have a vector field $F = <\sin y\cos z,yx^2,zy^2> $, and I have to find the surface integral of $F$ along the surface $S$ that is the boundary surface of $W$ and $S$ is a parabolid $z=x^2+y^2$ bounded by $z=4$ and $z=9$.

My attempt: I used the divergence theorem as the surface is closed (or at least my choice of integration parameters can make it closed). After doing the math I basically get div $F=x^2+y^2$. Now I use cylindrical coordinates system to parametrize the volume. I chose theta to lie between $0$ and $2\pi$ and $r$ to lie between $2$ and $3$. But what about my $z$? Where should it lie such that I can get the write answer which in this case is $665\pi/6$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your going to do it in the order $dV=rdzdrd\theta$. Then note that $z \in [4,9]$ for $r \in [0,2]$. But $z \in [r^2,9]$ for $r \in [2,3]$. So we need to split the integral into two as the bounds on $z$ change  depending on where we are:
[image]

$$\iint_{S} \vec F . d\vec S=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{4}^{9} r^2 r dz dr d\theta +\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{2}^{3} \int_{r^2}^{9} r^2 r dz dr d\theta=\frac{665}{6}\pi$$

Comment: Totally got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You had a typo in your problem. The vector field $F=\langle\sin y\cos z, zy^2,zx^2\rangle$.

The radius should range from $0$ to $\sqrt{z}$, since it varies with $z$. $z$ is from $4$ to $9$.